# Работа аутентификации Laravel через SMS

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Нужно привязать к сайту на ларавел авторизацию в личный кабинет через SMS (к слову, только она и будет использоваться, никаких прочих не будет). Правильным ли будет писать с нуля всю логику авторизации, т.е. не использовать "из коробки" всеми известный `make:auth`? Как правильно привязать это все к фасаду `Auth`, чтобы можно было пользоваться методами `Auth::guest()`, `Auth::user()` и т.д.? Заранее спасибо!

P.S. чтобы избежать кучи минусов, заранее скажу. Я не прошу тут готовое решение, я прошу лишь подсказать, что именно почитать, чтобы привязать свою собственную аутентификацию к фасаду Auth?

Answer (score 1):

Первое, что я бы предложил вам, так это прочитать вот этот раздел - [аутентификация пользователя в laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users)

Если я правильно представляю себе авторизацию через смс, то вам придется использоваться собственные методы, для того, чтобы, к примеру, проверить правильность введенного кода из отправленного смс, разумеется для этого придется создавать собственные методы в контроллерах. Ну а дальше самый простой вариант сделать что-то в таком виде:

```
// после проверки пользователя получаем его instance
Auth::login($user);// пользователь залогинен
```

Соответственно, после того, как пользователь авторизирован, вы можете спокойно пользоваться методами вроде `Auth::user()`. 
Собственно, по идее это самый простой вариант, чтобы пользоваться стандартными методами Laravel. Использовать ли `make:auth` или нет - решать вам. Какие-то вещи, которые он вам сгенерирует в любом случае пригодятся: тоже route для logout, к примеру.

Ну а второй вариант - делать свой собственный драйвер для авторизации.(в том же разделе есть варианты, которые описывают кастомизацию драйвера и создание собственных вариантов для авторизации)